# How to insert values into the object from the dictionary? (C#, Expression)

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, expression

I have a function that uses reflection:

```
    internal static void SetPropertiesFromDictionary(object entity, Dictionary<string, object> values)
    {
        var typeOfEntity = entity.GetType();

        var entityProperties = typeOfEntity
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance |                                        
                           BindingFlags.Public | 
                           BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

        foreach (var pi in entityProperties)
        {
            values.TryGetValue(pi.Name, out var value);
            if (value != null)
            {
                pi.SetValue(entity,value);
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I create an expression for setting properties so that I can use reflection only once?

Comment: what do you mean only once?

Comment: You will have to call Reflection for each item anyway. Even if you create some kind of "one-line" expression, it will get called for each item in dictionary.

You already have the crucial part called once. The method `SetValue` must be called for each item in dictionary separately, it writes to different object (property).

Comment: You can use the `PropertyInfo.GetGetMethod` to get the `MethodInfo` of the properties setter. Then use a matching `Delegate.CreateDelegate()` overload to create a delegate that you can cache to avoid reflection on any further call.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are you trying to achieve - optimize your program or make your code look cleaner. But you can consider this solution:

```
static void Main() {
  Dictionary<string, object> testDict = new Dictionary<string, object> {
    { "TestProperty1", 1 },
    { "TestProperty2", "value2" }
  };
  TestClass result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testDict));
}
class TestClass {
  public object TestProperty1 { get; set; }
  public object TestProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

So you just serialize your dictionary into a string and than deserialize this string into the object of the type. The trick is that dictionary serialized into json has the same structure as object serialized to json, so you can treat the same info as a dictionary with key-value pairs or an object with properties and values. And you don't need to take care about missing values.